# Retrun event.xdata from a function

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib, canvas, event-handling, global-variables

I have made a small gui to select points on a given image, plot the points, interpolate them and save them. I would like to make it so that the interpolated points are given as output of the function gui_pos(image) retrun, but I couldn't find the way to do it. So far I have fixed it saving the interpolated point in a .pckl file but it is not a good solution. 
The code is the following:

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
import pickle
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d

def interp_mia(x,y,xx):
    f= interp1d(x,y,fill_value="extrapolate")
    yy= f(xx)
    return yy

def onclick(event):

    plt.plot(event.xdata, event.ydata, '.')
    fig.canvas.draw()
    coordsx.append(event.xdata)
    coordsy.append(event.ydata)

    if (event.button == 3) :
        xx =  np.arange(np.min(coordsx),np.max(coordsx))
        yy = interp_mia(coordsx, coordsy, xx)
        print('you pressed', event.button)
        plt.plot(xx,yy,'k-')
        fig.canvas.draw()                                
        fig.canvas.mpl_disconnect(cid)
        dum = np.array((xx,yy))
        f = open('gui_pos.pckl', 'wb')
        pickle.dump(dum, f)
        f.close()

def gui_pos(image):

    global coordsx
    global coordsy
    global fig
    global cid
    global xx
    global yy
    global slit
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
    ax.imshow(image, origin="lower")
    coordsx = []
    coordsy = []
    cid = fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', onclick)    
    return
```

Any ideas?
Thank you,
Qarolina

Comment: The function cannot return a value that does not yet exist at the moment it returns. Where in your code do you want to call `plt.show()`?

Comment: I usually run --pylab but in general `plt.show()` should be right after  `cid = fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', onclick)`

Comment: In that case you can make `dum` global and return it from the function.

Comment: In which part of the code should I declare `global dum`? I tried adding it right before `dum = np.array((xx,yy))` but it doesn't work.

Comment: A global variable needs to be global in each scope it's used.